# Error updating Spring-data-jpa on MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I got an error on startup upgrading from version 1.4.3 to 1.5+ or 1.6.0;
I am using Hibernate 4.3.5

The exception is:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IAccountRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.model.entities.BaseEntity] does not define an IdClass

and the entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(EntityAuditListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Audited
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "isactive", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE")
    private boolean isActive = true;

    protected BaseEntity() {
    }

    protected BaseEntity(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    ........... more attributes and getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts", schema = "public")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_account", sequenceName = "seq_account", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Audited
public class Account extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_account")
    @Column(name = "accountid")
    private Long accountId;

    ---- more attributes and getters and setters
}
```

To me it looks like Spring-data-jpa checks hierarchy in the same way Hibernate does but considering the super class as an entity.

Do you know if it's my error or a bug and any workaround?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**

MY repositories are as follow:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IBaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
    public Page<T> findByIsActiveTrue(Pageable pageable);

    public List<T> findByIsActiveTrue();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface IAccountRepository extends IBaseRepository<Account, Long> {

    -- mix of queries by method name like:
    public Account findByAccountIdAndIsActiveTrue(Long accountId);

    -- and @Query like:
    @Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a.accountCreditLimit), 0) FROM Account a WHERE a.name = :name")
    public BigDecimal readAccountCreditLimits(@Param("name") String accountName);
}
------ and many more repositories as above
```

Comment: Do you have declared the BaseEntity in the persistence.xml?

Comment: not in the persistence.xml but in the app-context.xml:
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
....
<property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
....
</bean>
AND
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.model" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

Comment: As you have not annotated as `@Entity` this should not be a problem. Then I am as clueless as you now ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and many attempts, I found out the error was on my repository hierarchy.

So after improving my generics now it works as before.

---

From:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface IBaseAddressRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends IBaseRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

---

To:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface IBaseAddressRepository<T extends Address> extends IBaseRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

Does anyone know if this is the expected behaviour? Although it's much better to narrow generic types as much as possible, my old repository should work too as long as Address extends BaseRepository, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the the same problem upgrading from 1.4.3 with hibernate 4.3.5. My repository interfaces extend PagingAndSortingRepository. I found the below line in Spring data change log for 1.6.0:

- Can't use pagination (Pageable) with @IdClass entities (spring-data-jpa 1.4.3 & Hibernate 4.1.9). (DATAJPA-472)
  (source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/changelog.txt)

Replaced PagingAndSortingRepository with JpaRespository and seems to work fine.

Comment: My repositories already extend JpaRepository and JpaSpecificationExecutor. I'll update the answer with that info.

Comment: OK, I still had the same problem with some repository/entity tests but only those in a specific package that shared my base entities and entities that extend them. I ended up moving my base classes to separate packages, and made sure that those packages were not included in packages scanned by entity manager. That seemed to do the trick. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data tries to create an Implementation for your BaseRepository.
This requires an full Entity with @Entity, @Id.

It is possible to tell Spring that you don't need an Implemenation for the BaseRepository by adding the Annotation `@NoRepositoryBean`

This is how my "BaseRepository" looks like:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IsActiveAwareRepository<T extends AbstractEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID>{
    public Iterable<T> findByIsActive(Boolean isActive);
}
```